# Train tickets from Copenhagen airport to Aarhus, delayed flights and how to get seats and wifi

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, denmark, cph

I will be traveling from Copenhagen airport to Aarhus by train. I would like to make sure I get seats and also access to the wifi.  So I have two questions:

- If I book the tickets/seats online and the flight is delayed, is it valid on a later train?
- Do you have to pay for the wifi on the train, and if so how do you buy it without a Danish phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Some discounted tickets marketed as "DSB Orange" are only valid on a specific train, but ordinary tickets will be valid on any train no matter whether you have a matching seat reservation.

If you don't catch the train you have a reservation for, you will of course not be guaranteed a seat, but unless you run into the outbound commuter peak, your chances of finding a place to sit are excellent.

Most Danish trains don't require seat reservations; the exceptions are some *InterCity Bornholm* departures, which are not relevant for you.

(2) The wifi in intercity trains is free. There is a mandatory sign-on step, but it does not require a phone or even any credentials:

- Sign on to the wifi network named "TDC".
- Try to load any HTTP (not HTTPS) page; you will be redirected to a capture page in Danish.
- Ignore all the text, and click the big red button marked "Klik her".
- You now have internet connection.

*(This answer typed on the train after trying out above procedure)*

Comment: Thank you so much!  So are the train tickets valid for an entire day?

Comment: @felipa: They're valid for one journey at any time of the day.

Comment: Just to double check, would a DSB minigroup ticket (Seat reservation included)  also be valid for one journey at any time of the day?

Comment: @felipa: I called DSB and asked. The minigroup ticket must be used with seat reservations, but the ticket is not _tied_ to a particular reservation. So if you miss the train, you can still use the minigroup ticket together with new reservations for a later departure (which cost 30 DKK per traveler).